# Mongodb driver regex find

Tags: java, mongodb

```
    String pattern = ".*" + "a? I'm" + ".*";
    FindIterable<Document> document = collection.find(regex("mypost", pattern, "i")).sort(new Document("mypost", -1));
```

I want a regex that contains the terms "a? I'm". For some reason this pattern picks up collections with mypost as "? I'm" when I want only "a? I'm".

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that `?` has special meaning

> ? - Once or none

So your regex is basically saying - before " I'm" you can have `a` or not.

Your regex in fact should look like this:

`String pattern = ".*" + "a\\? I'm" + ".*";`

By adding `\\` you should specify that you want to use `?` as a character.

Comment: Okay that does it fix but now my issue is that I cant manually change every symbol with 2 `\\`'s since that part of the text isn't always fixed if that makes sense. Is there a command like exactText(string)

Comment: \\ Won't show as a character, why don't you experiment?

Comment: @FailingCoder I mean if I were send a request with a string such as "abc? I'm" RESTfully I wont know the position of every symbol

Comment: Experiment then.